# Problem with connecting in shader editor

Tags: node-editor

I can't connect `result` with `background`. When i'm trying to do it, blender opens list. I'm watching the blender course and there everything is working: `result` just connected with `background`

I have Blender 3.6.1
Guy in course has 2.93.4

1. List item

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can't connect an output to an output. Every output of one node is supposed to be connected to an input of another node.

Trying to connect an output to an output is like trying to connect a computer monitor to another computer monitor (in this case it would be connecting an input to another input, similarly nonsensical attempt). You wouldn't expect it to work, and some cables will have asymmetric ends on both sides to not allow you to do it. Similarly Blender doesn't allow you to do it, and won't allow an invalid connection (in this case; you still can make some invalid connections, e.g. connecting a  shader output to a  color input, producing a red=invalid link).

[image]

Notice how when a connection (valid or not) can be made, the + sign near the cursor disappears.

Answer (score 0):

If you drag from some input or output, and release in the middle of dragging, all available options of connecting appear. To be honest it's an extremely helpful feature. It's relativly new so if you watch some old tutorial you won't see it. If you want to connect it to an existing node, you just have to be a little bit careful and make sure to not release it  in the middle of dragging.